# Issue with linked list and truth table

Tags: c, linked-list, binary

So I'm trying to print the truth table of a gate with n inputs using linked lists. I tried the following but I'm running into a problem. If I use the for loops with bincombs, to print all possible combinations and to calculate the result, on both report and myandlst as shown below, it crashes. The problem is easily fixed if I print everything in myandlst but I want to avoid it. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct data
{
    int value;
    struct data * next;
} Data;
typedef Data * DataList;
typedef int (*CallBack)(DataList *inlist, int n);
int report(CallBack f, int n);
int getbit(int x, int p);
void bincombs(int * x, int n);
int myandlst(DataList *list, int n);

int main( )
{
    CallBack f ;
    report(myandlst, 4);
 
    return 0;
}

int getbit(int x, int p)
{
    return (x & (1<<p))!=0;
}

void bincombs(int * x, int n)
{
    static int state = 0 ;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        *x = getbit (state, i);
        x++;
    }
    state ++;
    return;
}

Data * createData( int value)
{
    Data * dataptr;
    dataptr = malloc(sizeof (Data));
    dataptr->value = value;
    dataptr->next = NULL;
    return dataptr;
}
void appendData(DataList *lstptr, Data *newptr)
{
    if (*lstptr==NULL)
    {
        *lstptr = newptr;
        return;
    }
    appendData( &((*lstptr)->next), newptr);

    return;
}

int myandlst (DataList *inlist, int n)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int * x = malloc (n*sizeof(int));
    k=1;
    for (i=0; i< (1<<n) ; i++)
    {
        bincombs(x, n);
        for (j=n-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            k*=x[j];
        }
        appendData(inlist,createData(k));
        k=1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int report(CallBack f, int n)
{
    DataList temp ;
    int * x = malloc (n*sizeof(int));
    int i,j;
    f(&temp, n);

    for (i=0; i< (1<<n) ; i++)
    {
        bincombs(x, n);
        for (j=n-1; j>=0; j--)
            printf("%d ", x[j]);
        printf("%d\n", temp -> value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

P.S This is an assignment and therefore the structure of the program is standard. I can't avoid using linked lists or changing the format of the functions too much.

Comment: Use a debugger to find out when and where it crashes. And examine the values of all involved variables.

Comment: A possible hint though: You use a lot of uninitilaized variables in your functions, for example `DataList temp ;` in the `report` function. That pointer will have an *indeterminate* value (look at it as garbage).

Comment: If there would one thing I would change *immediately* it would be getting rid of the type alias `DataList`. There are arguably only two reasons to hide pointer types in type aliases: blackbox "handle" APIs with data hiding, and callback pointer types. `DataList` fits *neither* of those. Fyi, `Callback` fits the latter, so that's a good candidate. After that, `DataList temp ;` declares an indeterminate pointer, whose value is relied on later for list building. At a minimum that should be `Data *temp = NULL;` That `DataList` "hides" it's pointer roots is reason enough for my first suggestion.

Comment: It seems changing it to `DataList temp = NULL;` made it work as you guys suggested.

Comment: `-fsanitize=addr` is a help for debugging crashes